# NoSuchElement using scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

```
I have declared two strings and reading the input using Scanner(System.in).
```

After this when i am closing the Scanner and again reading the another input using the  Scanner,then it throws an error: **NoSuchElementException**.
Please guide me on this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;  

public class NumericInput

{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Declarations
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string1;
    String string2;

   // Prompts 
    System.out.println("Enter the value of the First String .");
   // Read in values  
    string1 = in.nextLine();
    // When i am commenting below line(in.close) code is working properly. 
    in.close();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Now enter another value.");
    string2 = sc.next();
    sc.close();

    System.out.println("Here is what you entered: ");
    System.out.println(string1 + " and " + string2);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--) your scanner it also closes [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) input stream, you are using it again, but it's closed, so   when you try to use `Scanner` again, no open `System.in` stream is found.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to close a Scanner, since it implements *AutoCloseable* interface you should declare resources in try-with-resources as of java 7. If closing Scanner is an issue.

```
try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)){
 // do stuff here without closing
}

 catch(Exception){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: code did not open `System.in`, so better not close it (indirectly by closing the `Scanner`s)